# Extended menu on a different domain

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, cross-domain

My client has a Drupal 6 site.

They are now adding another domain to the same site, but the different domain is going to be used by another branch of their company. Therefore, they need some additional content, specific to the other branch's geographic area, in the menu, as well as a slightly different theme on the front page.

So, to make it clearer: *domain1.com* and *domain2.com* both point to the very same installation of Drupal on one server, but not 100% of the content is shared between them.

I don't usually work with Drupal, so I'm not sure how to tackle this. How would you approach the issue? Is there a way to add or remove a single menu item depending on the domain that is being used? Is there a way to use a different view in the same scenario?

Both contrib modules and programmatic solutions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Domain Access](http://drupal.org/project/domain) module allows you to have more than one domain with the same database. You can set different themes in the interface per site. This is a good option especially if you have sites where some of the content is shared, while other content only appears on one of the sites. Once it's installed, you'll see an option on the node edit screen to select which sites the content should appear in. Very easy for content editors.

Domain Access is good at managing two different domains with affiliate content (as that's what is designed to do), it does require more configuration that most modules and you need to have control over your site's DNS.

Another good option might be to use [Organic Groups](http://drupal.org/project/og). I use this on a site much like the one you're describing. Like Domain Access, you can share the same piece of content with multiple groups. It's just that the Domain Access module is probably a little more streamlined as it's designed to do what you're describing, while OG may require slightly more tweaking.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I've come across Domain Access, but assumed its purpose was different. What kind of control over the DNS is required? I'm not 100% sure whether the site is on a shared host (likely) or a private one (unlikely)...

Comment: I'm not a DNS expert, but I think it usually means setting up virtual hosts so they both point to the same Drupal site. The documentation here (http://drupal.org/node/1096954) gives a few examples.

Comment: Ah, I get it. Depending on the host, this might mean creating an appropriate symlink from one domain's folder to another or simply creating a domain alias so that both use the same source directory. I think that's doable. I'll experiment with the module then, thank you.

Comment: No problem. Good luck and hope it helps.

Comment: I hope so too. I'll try it tomorrow (hopefully...) and tell you how it went :P.

Answer (score 0):

This use case would suit using a Drupal multisite configuration (http://drupal.org/node/43816) using shared tables. In essence, one site would live in /sites/site1, the other in /sites/site2, with each settings.php file pointing the tables to a shared database table.

Comment: I've never worked with a multisite setup. If I create two sites within the Drupal install and let them use the same database, wouldn't they end up being exact duplicates?